# set images in listView item

Tags: android, listview

i have made MainActivity class in which i want to set icon in list view

code is here

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

static  String classes[]={"StartingPoint","Example1","Example2","Example3","Example4","Example5","Example6","Example7"};
    static final Integer[] imgid = {R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String  cheese=classes[position];

        try {
            Class myclass=Class.forName("com.example.listmenu."+cheese);
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,myclass);
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

i want to set icon in list view item ....plz help me i stuck with this problem ?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Please go thro this link for answer.

Comment: have a look at this. http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429 and http://www.edureka.in/blog/android-widgets-custom-listview/

Comment: look at this also http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/

Answer (score 1):

make your custom adapter and pass array of text and image

```
 public class AboutAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private Context mcontext;
        private Strig[] arrayList;

        public AboutAdapter(Context context, Strig[] arrayList) {
            this.mcontext = context;
            this.arrayList= arrayList;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder {
            TextView txtname;
            ImageView imag;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            Holder holder;
            if (vi == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_aboutlist, null);
                holder = new Holder();

                holder.txtname = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.raw_about_txt_name);
                holder.imag = (ImageView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.raw_about_img);

                vi.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (Holder) vi.getTag();
            }

 holder.txtname.setText(arrayList[position]);

// same as for image pass array of image and set 

    holder.imag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.explr_img_selector);
            return vi;
        }

    }
```

and then set adapter in listview as shown below

```
AboutAdapter aboutAdapter = new AboutAdapter(AboutActivity.this, arrayList);
listView.setAdapter(aboutAdapter);
```